# If $H(x)$ is a one-way function, is $f(x)=H(x)\cdot x^{-1}$ a one-way function?

Tags: one-way-function

Assume $S$ is a domain. $S' \subseteq S$ and all elements in $S'$ are invertible.  $H:S'\rightarrow S$. If $H(x)$ is a one-way function, is $f(x)=H(x)\cdot x^{-1}$ a one-way function?

Comment: It's not clear what the $\cdot$ and $x^{-1}$ are. Plus $f$ must be restricted to a domain where $x$ is invertible, which is unnatural for $H$.

Comment: Have you tried reasoning by contradiction and using the formal definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function?

Answer (score -1):

Let ${y=x^{-1}}$. if ${f(x)}$ is a bijective function. then we can avoid ${H(x) \cdot y= H(x) \cdot y'}$, where every ${x}$ has unique ${f(x)}$

Comment: If that's an answer, I don't get it. $f$ being injective does not imply $f$ one-way.

Comment: @fgrieu, Yes, firstly if ${f(x)=H(x).y}$ then , there is a higher possibility that f(x) is not a bijective,  in fact it has more chances of being surjective..     Because if H(x) and f(x) is a n bit function,  and  ${ \cdot}$ is a sign of multiplication then we have to reduce to some modulo. and which may result that ${f(x)}$ is surjective. Also, if size of f(x)  > H(x) , then we  may also have  collision at some point.